# Bitrix\Sale\Order::getList() получить количество выбранных записей

Tags: битрикс

Получаю заказы методом Bitrix\Sale\Order::getList()
через `runtime` поле пытаюсь достать количество обработанных записей.
Вот так:

```
,'runtime' => array(
  new Entity\ExpressionField('CNT', 'COUNT(*)')
```

)

как описано в доке: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5753&LESSON_PATH=3913.5062.5748.5063.5753

Но возвращается всегда 1 !

Что я не так делаю? Подскажите пожалуйста
Буду сильно благодарен

Вот используемый код:

```
        if (is_null($nPageSize)) {
        $nPageSize = 10;
    }

    if (is_null($nPage)) {
        $nPage = 1;
    }

    $orders = Bitrix\Sale\Order::getList([
                                    'select' => ['*','CNT']
                                    ,'filter' => ['USER_ID' => $USER->GetID()]
                                    ,'order' => ['ID'=>'DESC']
                                    ,'limit' => $nPageSize
                                    ,'offset' => $nPageSize*($nPage-1)
                                    ,'runtime' => array(
                                                new Entity\ExpressionField('CNT', 'COUNT(*)')
                                            )
    ]);
```

В начале класса подключены:

```
 use Bitrix\Sale;
 use Bitrix\Main\Entity;
 use Bitrix\Main\Entity\ExpressionField;
```

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить без ограничения на кол-во записей.

Comment: да похоже это единственный способ в данном случае вытащить кол-во заказов. Т.е. достать без ограничений, потом использовать Bitrix\Sale\Order::getList()->getSelectedRowsCount() и уже на основе этого дергать с нужными офсетами

Comment: Возможно у вас ошибка где-то в передаче ограничений. Либо система криво считает. Я бы рекомендовал уточнить у поддержки.